# What's the best way to prevent water from collecting underneath a soap bar?

Tags: home, water, bathroom, organization

I've used regular soap dishes for most of my life, but the water would always collect underneath the dish, which is annoying.

So I started putting a washrag underneath the dish to collect the water, but this obviously gets dirty and looks bad.

Finally, I put the soap on the built-in soap dish holder above the sink, but now the soapy water drips down and cakes on the faucet below it.

Does anyone else have better ideas for how to collect or prevent this water?

Comment: You can Google "self draining soap dish" and find several good designs.

Comment: Oh interesting.  Just ordered one.  We'll see if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: I have one I bring on vacations with me, since many hotel showers don't have good soap dishes (or any soap dishes!).

Comment: I am using it now; besides being slightly clunky, it seems to be the best alternative.  Nicer looking than a sponge.  The water goes straight to the sink bowl!  Ah, capitalism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try putting a sponge in the soap dish and placing the soap on the sponge.  The sponge performs 2 functions: it raises the soap above any collected water and it absorbs water from the soap.

Comment: My sponge is my soap dish, and it [cleans up my beard trimmings](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-does-one-efficiently-clean-up-hair-from-sink-after-shaving-or-trimming-beard#comment9186_6380).

Answer (score 3):

"The best" is unanswerable, but any object that raises the soap out of any pooled water and lets air circulate on all sides will do the job. I currently use a plastic disk originally intended for holding toys to the sides of a tub; it has many small suction cups on each side, with space between them that allow airflow. I've seen "palm combs" used for the purpose; the many points spread across the surface should do the same thing. A small brush could work. Something with a corrugated surface could work. A grill of some sort. And so on. .

Another solution I've seen is a funnel-like holder which lets water drain away. That works better mounted to the wall of a shower than on a sink, I think.

The same basic principle applies in all cases: lift the soap off the wet surface, support it with minimum contact.

Answer (score 2):

***MAGNETS***

My "solution" involves suspension in mid-air using a magnetic soap holder. The "magnet" is smooth and leaves a lot of soap area free to do your business. Any kind of soap bar works with this gizmo. The whole fixture isn't that unattractive and it will be the topic of conversation for everyone who comes away from your sink.

Comment: How do you attach the magnet to your soap, or can you only buy special soap that comes with the magnet?

Comment: @kamuro the soap holder comes with a metal thingy similar to a crown cork / bottle cap. You push it in any random bar of soap of your choice, the ribbed edge holds onto the soap.

Comment: Stan, they are so "retro" - I remember them from when I was a kid like back in the dark ages ^_^

Comment: Very interesting; I haven't seen this before.